# difference time in 2 columns in excel with full date and hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel in two columns I got data like this:

```
2023/11/30 16:59:43 | 2023/11/30 16:56:44
```

and I want to get in new column difference in seconds. How to do it?

Comment: What did you try and what is the issue you encounter?

Comment: Google: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-e1c78778-749b-49a3-b13e-737715505ff6

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, dates/times are simple numbers, where 1 stands for 1 day. In order to know the amount of seconds, you need to multiply:

- By 24 (there are 24 hours in a day)
- by 60 (there are 60 minutes in an hour)
- again by 60 (there are 60 seconds in a minute)

So, basically, you subtract two dates/times, multiply the difference by `24*60*60` and (if needed) convert it to a regular number (using cell formatting).

Answer (score -1):

Please check this ! Excel Date & time are stored as numbers . Hence you need to multiply the difference between two dates with 1 day(24 hours) and 1 hour( 60 mins) and 1 minute( 60 seconds).

[image]

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how the calculation works and remove the text "It's the same answer as Dominique mentioned in his answer.". You're not in control of Dominque's answer and he/she may delete it leaving this answer hard to understand.